# fail to link cuda example with clang++-9 under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-18.04, clang++

I am trying to follow the example in
https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#invoking-clang
I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, clang version 9.0.0-2
The device I have is (snippet from the output of deviceQuery):

```
Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro P520"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          10.2 / 10.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
```

I ran the command:

```
clang++-9 --verbose --cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-10.2 axpy.cu -o axpy --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_61 -L/usr/local/cuda-10.2 -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

And the output is:

```
clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /usr/local/cuda-10.2, version unknown
clang: error: cannot find libdevice for sm_61. Provide path to different CUDA installation via --cuda-path, or pass -nocudalib to build without linking with libdevice.
```

As far as I can tell, libdevice is right where it should be:

```
~>ls /usr/local/cuda-10.2/nvvm/libdevice/
libdevice.10.bc
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Added Nov 2020:**
Following @ArtemB comment, I tried running it with clang++-10, which throws a warning, but compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: Are you *really* sure there is only one libdevice installed? What does verbose output from clang show?

Comment: +talonmies, a) there are two cudas, but I pointed at the 10.2. I edited the question to include the command with explicit pointing to the 10.2 (using cuda path), the verbose argument, and the output (same problem of course). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently clang was rather particular about CUDA versions. I've relaxed it a bit lately, so clang-10 is more lenient and will attempt to use a newer CUDA version at a feature parity with the latest supported CUDA version (currently 10.1). It will also issue a warning. It does work with CUDA-11.0 well enough to compile Tensorflow.

CUDA-11.1 (and I believe 11.0 update1 on windows) have dropped the version.txt file from the distribution and that will break CUDA compilation with the currently released clang versions, again. This should be fixed in clang-11.0.1 when it's released (version match with CUDA is purely coincidental).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: The version of cuda my driver supports (10.2) is too current for my clang (9.0.0).

Here is the top of the output of `nvidia-smi` on my machine:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
```

So my driver indeed supports cuda-10.2. However, it seems this version *is not* supported by clang 9.0.0. Indeed when running the above command with the extra flag `-nocudalib` , one gets the following response (only showing the last lines):

```
In file included from <built-in>:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:52:2: error: "Unsupported CUDA version!"
#error "Unsupported CUDA version!"
 ^
axpy.cu:23:7: error: use of undeclared identifier cudaConfigureCall
  axpy<<<1, kDataLen>>>(a, device_x, device_y);
      ^
2 errors generated when compiling for sm_61.
```

When inspecting the offending file (the clang cuda runtime wrapper), one sees the following in lines 48-53:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#if !defined(CUDA_VERSION)
#error "cuda.h did not define CUDA_VERSION"
#elif CUDA_VERSION < 7000 || CUDA_VERSION > 10010
#error "Unsupported CUDA version!"
#endif
```

Comment: Until recently clang was rather particular about CUDA versions. I've relaxed it a bit lately, so clang-10 is more lenient and will attempt to use a newer CUDA version at a feature parity with the latest supported CUDA version. It will also issue a warning. It does work with CUDA-11 well enough to compile Tensorflow.

Comment: @ArtemB : Thanks. I'll try it again

Comment: @ArtemB, if you'll write it as answer I'll move the accept from my answer to yours - I tried it and it worked

Comment: Added an answer with an update about recent developments.